# Displaying images in Bitmap item render Flex 4 Android mobile

Tags: android, image, apache-flex, path

Platform - Flex 4.6 Android export.

I have this saved file:
/data/data/air.AppName.debug/AppName.debug/Local Store/all/541851_3348522468594_1134799584_3205199_214963169_n.jpg

I trying to display this image using bitmapImage in custom ItemRender. 
But I can't see anything. Item is created but without showing the image.
When I tested on desktp it's working on show the immage, but on the device don't work.
Is it the reason in path format? Or maybe some restrictions?

FOUND THE SOLUTION. The problem can be resolved adding this to the begining file:/// .

So this work:
file:///data/data/air.AppName.debug/AppName.debug/Local Store/all/541851_3348522468594_1134799584_3205199_214963169_n.jpg

Thanks for involving.

Comment: How did you save it?  Are you getting an error?  How did you test on the desktop (AKA Emulator or something different?)  Are you sure that the image is on the device?

Comment: FOUND THE SOLUTION. The problem can be resolved adding this to the begining file:/// .

So this work: file:///data/data/air.AppName.debug/AppName.debug/Local Store/all/541851_3348522468594_1134799584_3205199_214963169_n.jpg

Thanks for involving.

Comment: Try it with two / instead of three.  That would be how a URL is traditionally formed.